# Drawing on a plane in SceneKit

Tags: ios, scenekit

I created a SCNPlane in my scene. I set the diffuse content of the SCNPlane to an image. Now I need to display other details on the plane (e.g. the name of the plane, and other simple drawings like an arrow).

This seems like a simple task but I could not find any relevant information. Should I create other geometries and attach them to the plane? If so, how do I do that without z-fighting occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Materials in SceneKit are very flexible. When you are assigning something to the `diffuse` or `ambient` property you are assigning a [`SCNMaterialProperty`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty). From Apples docs you can assign:

> - An image object, or a path or URL to an image file
> - A specially formatted image or array of six images to be used as a cube map
> - A **Core Animation layer or layer hierarchy**, which itself may contain animated content
> - A SpriteKit texture providing a static image, or an **entire SpriteKit scene** rendering animated 2D content.

I haven't got the Core Animations layers to work properly, maybe someone else can give more information on it, but I have been using [SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/spritekit/) and it is really easy to set up.

1. Create a `SKScene` and add animate it as much as you want
2. Set the size of your scene. SceneKit will scale this up if your plane is bigger than your size.
3. Add it to your materials `diffuse` property

Comment: I set an image as the diffuse content of my plane. When user selects the plane, I want to display graphic information on the plane. It makes sense to me to draw on the plane, however I do not know how to. It seems counterintuitive to make a new SKScene every time and reset the content of my plane. Is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: Display your image using SpriteKit and animate and change the `SKScene` as you need it

Comment: Ah I see. That makes sense. Could users interact with individual spritekit nodes through tap gesture in the SKScene, which is set as the content of the plane?